# is it possible to navigate to another route and going to a specific bookmark right after?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, bookmarks

so I'm using Next.js which is built on react.js and here is the problem:

I want to be able to navigate to another route and then going to a specific div in that destination route using HTML 5 bookmark feature.

obviously in the normal way this won't work by just giving the nav items the id of a div since the content of the page hasn't been rendered yet so it has to be done after the request has been sent.

is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Is your destination page a static page or does it request some data from server via AJAX?

Comment: yeah it does send requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML 5 Bookmarks indeed won't work if your destination page requests target content from backend server client side (e.g. via XHR or Fetch).

To solve this issue with Next.js, you can **enable server-side rendering for you destination page** by loading the target content in a `getInitialProps` method:

```js
function DestinationPage({ targetContent }) {
  // render your target content somehow
}

DestinationPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const targetContent = await fetch(backendUrl);
  return { targetContent };
}

export default DestinationPage;
```

Thus you will request your target content server-side and render a page already fed with your content in a browser. **And thus your bookmarks will be initially present on your page.**

You can read more about how to switch a Next.js page to server-side rendering mode in [this blog post](https://antoncodes.com/article/nextjs-ssg-vs-ssr-part-1-static-page#enter-getinitialprops).

Comment: well the funny thing is that i was going to switch it to server side rendering but i totally forgot that there won't be such a problem because exactly as you said "your bookmarks will be initially present on your page", thanks so much, that helped a ton

Comment: always glad to help!